# Почему в этом случае объект-обертка не удаляется?

Tags: javascript, объекты, методы

Не совсем понимаю как работают объекты-обертки. Пишется, что такой тип объектов удаляется сразу после использования.

[Источник](https://learn.javascript.ru/primitives-methods#primitiv-kak-obekt)

> ...создаётся специальный «объект-обёртка», который предоставляет нужную функциональность, а после удаляется.

В этом случае это вполне понятно.

```
let str = 'hello';
console.log(str.toUpperCase()); //HELLO
```

Тут на момент обращения к свойству примитивного типа данных создается объект-обертка `String` с помощью функции-конструктора `new String()`. После обращения к св-ву `toUpperCase()` объекта-обертки `String`, объект `String` удаляется.

Почему же тогда здесь объект-обертка сохраняется? Выводится тип данных `object`.

```
let a = 10;
let b = new Boolean(a);
console.log(b); //object
```

Когда вообще обертка удаляется?

Comment: в зависимости от реализации «объект-обёртка» может и не создаваться. В последнем примере нет никакой обертки. Есть обычный объект.